# Get all from Main-Table where Date-Field in Subtable is older than 365 Days - just a bit more complex

Tags: sql, t-sql

Alright, first of all, the relations

**Table Customers:**

I have a table "Customers" with the fields "ID" and "mainID", which basically provide a hierarchy. Each customer gets an unique "ID". 
In the Customers Table are companies and employees. The employees contain the "ID" from their company in their "mainID" field.

For example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJSLL.png)

As you can see, the entries with "ID" = 2 or 3 are employees of 1 because their "mainID" is the "ID" (= 1) from their company.

**Table Communication:**

Then there is the table "Communication" which holds all communication you had with the customer selected above. The relation to "Customers" is made through the field "superID" which refers to the "ID" field in "Customers". The date when communication was made is held in the field "DATECREATE".

**My Goal:**

I need all **companies** from table "Customers" where the newest communication **of all their employees** is older than 365 days.

**Here's what I have:**

```
SELECT B.DATECREATE, A.* 
FROM CUSTOMERS A 
INNER JOIN COMMUNICATION B ON A.ID = B.SUPERID 
WHERE 
   DATEDIFF(DAY, B.DATECREATE, GETDATE()) >= 365 
   /* AND A.SYMBOL0 = 'Interessent' OR A.SYMBOL0 = 'Bestandskunde'*/;
```

Sadly, I get all companies where at one or more employees hasn't had any communication since a year, but I only need the companies where all of the employees haven't had any communication since a year.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and check the *minimum* date:

```
select c.mainid
from customers c join
     communication co
     on c.id = b.superid
group by c.mainid
having max(co.datecreate) < dateadd(day, -365, getdate());
```

EDIT:

If you want lots of columns, use window functions:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             max(co.date_create) over (partition by c.mainid) as max_datecreate
      from customers c join
           communication co
           on c.id = b.superid
     ) c
where max_datecreate < dateadd(day, -365, getdate()) and
      datecreate = max_datecreate;   -- get only one row per customer
```

Comment: Seems to work for me, but what I maybe forgot to mention is, within this select I need to get multiple Customer fields in my result

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Somehow I don't get where the "max_datecreate" comes from...

Comment: The query works now without any errors, however, I don't get any results, as if no entry would match my conditions...

Comment: @arvenyon . . . That would suggest that no entry matches the conditions.  Run the first query without the `having` and with `max(datecreate)` to see what the most recent date is for each company.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help you further.

**Declaration of tables**

```
DECLARE @tCustomers TABLE (ID INT, MAINID INT) INSERT INTO @tCustomers VALUES 
(1, 1), --Company A 
(2, 1), --Employee A of Company A
(3, 1), --Employee B of Company A
(4, 4), --Company B
(5, 4)  --Employee A of Company B

DECLARE @tCommunication TABLE (ID INT, SuperId INT, DateCreated DATE, Communication VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @tCommunication VALUES
(1, 2, '20180101','abcdefghijkl'),  --Comm of Employee A of Company A
(2, 2, '20171001','abcdefghijkl'),  --Comm of Employee A of Company A
(3, 3, '20191002','abcdefghijkl'),  --Comm of Employee B of Company A
(4, 5, '20171003','mnopqrstuvwxyz') --Comm of Employee A of Company B
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT c.ID, c.MAINID AS CompanyID, e.ID AS EmployeeId
FROM    @tCustomers e
    INNER JOIN (    SELECT  SuperId --Comm of an Employee older than 365 days
                    FROM    @tCommunication
                    WHERE   DATEDIFF(DAY, DateCreated, GETDATE()) > 365
                ) a 
        ON a.SuperId = e.ID
    INNER JOIN @tCustomers c
        ON c.ID = e.MAINID
```

**Result**

```
ID | CompanyID | EmployeeId
===========================
1  | 1         | 2
4  | 4         | 5
```

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for the help! This works perfectly, except...
that I need all companies, where ALL of the employees haven't  had any contact since a year or more.
With this solution, I get all companies, where ONE or more of the employees haven't had contact.